# Load webpage inside iframe but replace a part of url inside iframe page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, vbscript

My first question here :)

I want a way to load a page inside iframe while changing/replacing a part of the urls of any links present in the webpage with alternate text.

eg.
Suppose we load a website in iframe like "mywebsite.com"  which has a link to another site inside the loaded page

eg. http s://www.facebook.com/abcd?id=text
    http s://www.facebook.com/efgh?id=text

.

Then I want the website inside iframe to be loaded with custom urls like:

eg. http s://www.facebook.com/abcd?id=alternatetext
    http s://www.facebook.com/efgh?id=alternatetext

Basically I need a way to replace "text" to "alternatetext" .. ON THE FLY while rendering the webpage inside iframe.

How do I do it?
Help me people..

Thanks.

Comment: For security reasons, that is completely impossible.

Comment: sure, security exists everywhere. But it cannot be impossible. For I have used a firefox addon called Tamperdata. It can change code of the loaded website like small images, etc and it is completely legal to use it. What I am saying is that there has to be a way to load the site in a container->change the links->load the changed website in an iframe. This does not alter the actual website in any manner. It just changes the way it looks on my website. I gave facebook just for example. I wanted to load my own website and change its link when loaded in an iframe.

Comment: So where and what is the question?

Comment: Is my question unclear?

Comment: @Robin: Addins are different; if you want to write an addin, you should say so.  If you control the target site, you should also say so.

Comment: And, wrong; within those constraints, it is and _must be_ impossible, or you could silently steal data and/or do perfect phishing.

Comment: Almost every member who knows programming knows what phishing is. But I am keeping an open mind here. **This problem is soo difficult that no one is coming up with a clear answer/workpath.**  _We all respect LAW and SECURITY._ (so lets not discuss on the subject of law and security)

Comment: I prefer to host a script on my hosting to do this job. Addon will not be useful as my visitors may not prefer to install the addon and I will lose them.

Answer (score -1):

This is completely possible. But I think you may be far off on this. Since you do not include any JavaScript I assume that you have not made any head way on that. This is going to be deep and take some fine tuning, its not just some code snippet that someone can give you. It can totally be done with a scripting language. I recommend you take the time to learn a server side language. I personally use VB.NET at work. You will be amazed with the possibilities.

On another note, if Facebook found out you were displaying their pages online and modifying their links they would surely take some action.

I recommend this question be closed.

Comment: Thank you for shedding light here. But as I said I used facebook for an example purpose only. I know that they can technically sue me for this. But that is not the point. I just wanted to do it with my own websites. I dont want to fill my hosting with copies of same website pages only because I want to change some data on it.

Comment: I intend to create tens of thousands of iterations of my website without creating those many copies. That is easily possible if someone could create a script which works as I described in the question. Secondly, It is easy to change huge number of websites by changing  a code in just one script. (Therefore this question need NOT be closed)

Comment: If it was that easy for me then I would have not posted this question here. Therefore I sincerely request brilliant minds to contribute to this if possible.